# About touch events for imported 3d model in NinevehGL framework

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, 3d-rendering

I am rotating a 3d model with this code:

```
_mesh = [[NGLMesh alloc] initWithFile:@"01.obj" settings:settings delegate:self];

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    UITouch *touch;
    CGPoint pointA,pointB;

    if ([touches count]== 1) {

        touch = [[touches allObjects]objectAtIndex:0];
        pointA = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        pointB = [touch previousLocationInView:self.view];
        //      _mesh.rotateY -= (pointA.x - pointB.x) * 0.5f;
        //      _mesh.rotateX -= (pointA.y - pointB.y) * 0.5f;

        _mesh.rotateY += (pointA.x - pointB.x) * 0.5f;
    _mesh.rotateX += (pointA.y - pointB.y) * 0.5f;
    }
}
```

The code rotates like it's supposed to, but it rotates no matter where in the view I tap. I'd like it to only rotate while touching inside the imported model. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

For this,You have to manually get the 3d model object frame (corresponding to the screen) and comparer with the current touch location using **`CGRectContainsPoint`** in **`touchesMoved`** delegate.

Write the code **`_mesh.rotate`** only if  the result `CGRectContainsPoint` returns YES.

**Note:** NinevehGL have their [**own forum**](http://nineveh.gl/community/forum/) to discuss thing related to the framework. Please post the queries there to get good and quick responses.

Comment: Thank you for your reply..Is there any method to get the frame for 3d object ? i didn't find any..

Comment: I think better to post your queries in http://nineveh.gl/community/forum/  they will reply within one day

Answer (score 1):

Following code might help you to some extent,

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{  
[super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

UITouch *touch;
CGPoint pointA,pointB;
if ([touches count]== 1)
{
    touch = [[touches allObjects]objectAtIndex:0];
    pointA = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    pointB = [touch previousLocationInView:self.view];

    NGLTouching touchingStruct = [_camera touchingUnderPoint: pointA];

    if (touchingStruct.mesh)   
    {
        _mesh.rotateY += (pointA.x - pointB.x) * 0.5f;
        _mesh.rotateX += (pointA.y - pointB.y) * 0.5f;
    }
}
```

But still it wont change the bounding box of the mesh. You can refer [this](http://nineveh.gl/community/forum/touching_collada_meshes) blog post.